# Ajax deferreds with Prototype js

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

Is there an ajax deferreds concept in prototype js similar to what jQuery has?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results with the normal [Ajax callbacks](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/) - or if you want to attach an event on a bigger scale then look at the [Ajax.Responders documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/)